# Append the formula of the selected cell

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I want to realise the following scenario: a user selects a cell holding a formula, clicks on the `test` button of my add-in, then my `test` function reads the formula of the selected cell, append `+RAND()` to it, and write it back to the workbook.

The following code reads well the formula of the selected cell, but it does not write back well. I am not sure if (the second) `return ctx.sync()` is correctly used.

Additionally, I don't know if I should use `getSelectedDataAsync` and `setSelectedDataAsync` (rather than `getSelectedRange`) in the whole scenario.

Could anyone help?

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    Office.initialize = function(reason) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            app.initialize();
            $('#test').click(test);
        });
    }
    ;

    function test() {
        Excel.run(function(ctx) {
            var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
            selectedRange.load(["formulas"]);
            return ctx.sync().then(function() {
                console.log(selectedRange.formulas[0][0]);
                var x = selectedRange.formulas[0][0] + "+RAND()";
                selectedRange.formulas[0][0] = x;
                return ctx.sync();
            })
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("done");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is that you are trying to assign to an individual element in the formula context object. Instead use:

```
selectedRange.formulas = x;
```

or

```
selectedRange.formulas = [[x]];
```

Comment: Thank you... and in which cases we should use `getSelectedDataAsync` and `setSelectedDataAsync` rather than `getSelectedRange`?

Comment: There are several reasons to use getSelectedRange. For your purposes, the relevant reason is that setSelectedDataAsync and getSelectedDataAsync do not support formulas - only values. Another common reason to use getSelectedRange is to enable multiple read/write operations in a single asynchronous call whereas getSelectedDataAsync and setSelectedDataAsync can perform only one per call. The only reason to avoid getSelectedRange is if you need your add-in to work in places where that API isn't supported, like Excel 2013.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, it worked... Additionally, I tried to remove the second `return ctx.sync();`, it still worked. So, is it really necessary?

Comment: Besides, asynchronous programming is not very straightforward to me; I get used to VBA programming. If you did this scenario (ie, read formula -> modify it -> write it back), would you code in a similar structure (ie, load -> `return ctx.sync().then(function() {` -> write back)?

Comment: @SoftTimur, re. your 2 questions from above:  the reason that `.formulas = x` and `.formulas = [[x]]` both work is that in the former case we will spread the x formula onto all the cells in the range.  In the case of a single cell, either one will have identical effect.

As for why you need the last "return ctx.sync()" -- strictly speaking you don't, because Excel.run will do one final "sync" for you anyway, if there are any pending requests.  It is still a good idea to be explicit about it, though, to ensure that you're aware of the asynchrony and that you don't break the promise chain.